# Finding average of irregular number of rows in Excel

Tags: python, r, excel, vba

I have a data like this:

[image]

I want to find the average salary of all employees- As, Bs, Cs and Ds. I would like to know if there is any short cut to do the same as the number of employees is very large in my dataset. I tried using if else, but it turned out to be impractical. Do let me know if the same can be done in any other programming language.

Comment: `tapply(df$Salary, df$Name, mean)` Or with `aggregate`, `aggregate(Salary~Name, df, mean)`

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy in R. Assuming your file is saved as `data.csv` then

```
df = read.csv("data.csv")
sapply(split(df$Salary, df$Name), mean)
```